# How to add new attribute that need to be calculated recursively in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to dynamically add new attribute to all of the items in an array using map. But while adding it to each item, the value of this attribute is the sum of all previous items newly added attribute

Consider this example :

```
let persons = [{
"name": "A",
 "salary": 2
}, {
"name": "B",
 "salary": 5
},{
"name":"C",
"salary":12
}];
```

I want to return :

```
[{
    "name": "A",
     "salary": 2,
     "sumSalary":2
    }, {
    "name": "B",
     "salary": 5,
     "sumSalary":7
    },{
    "name":"C",
    "salary":12,
    "sumSalary":19
   }];
```

I've tried this one:

```
let mutatedPersons = persons.map((currentValue, index, mutatedPersons) => ({
  ...currentValue,
    sumSalary: currentValue.name === 'A' ? currentValue.salary : mutatedPersons[index - 1].sumSalary + currentValue.salary
}))
```

but i keep getting this :

```
[
  0: {name: "A", salary: 2, sumSalary: 2}
  1: {name: "B", salary: 5, sumSalary: NaN}
  2: {name: "C", salary: 12, sumSalary: NaN}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mutatedPersons` you refer to is the original array (see [map's parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters)), and not the updated array, which doesn't actually exist before the map end. You can cache the previous sum in an external variable (`prevSumSalary`), and use it as the basis of the new one:

```js
const persons = [{ name: "A", salary: 2 }, { name: "B", salary: 5 }, { name: "C", salary: 12 }]

let prevSumSalary = 0;
const mutatedPersons = persons.map((currentValue, index) => ({
  ...currentValue,
    sumSalary: (prevSumSalary = prevSumSalary + currentValue.salary)
}))

console.log(mutatedPersons);
```

Another option is to use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), since you have access to the accumulated values:

```js
const persons = [{ name: "A", salary: 2 }, { name: "B", salary: 5 }, { name: "C", salary: 12 }]

const mutatedPersons = persons.reduce((r, currentValue) => [...r, 
  ({
    ...currentValue,
      sumSalary: currentValue.salary + (r.length && r[r.length - 1].sumSalary)
  })
], [])

console.log(mutatedPersons);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure over `sum` and take it for added `sumSalary` property.

```js
var data = [{ name: "A", salary: 2 }, { name: "B", salary: 5 }, { name: "C", salary: 12 }],
    result = data.map((sum => o => ({ ...o, sumSalary: sum += o.salary }))(0));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let persons = [{
"name": "A",
 "salary": 2
}, {
"name": "B",
 "salary": 5
},{
"name":"C",
"salary":12
}];

let sum = 0;
persons.map(curr => {
  sum += curr.salary;
  curr.sumSalary = sum;
});

console.log(persons);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal case for `Array#reduce`.

One can use an *accumulator* (the whole `salarySum`) to get direct access to the last `salarySum` value.

Whenever one thinks about an *aggregate function*, one should immediately think about `Array#reduce` in first place!

Also, I've provided you a solution which doesn't mutate the source `persons` but it creates a new array which has `salarySum` on each item:

```js
const persons = [{
  name: "A",
  salary: 2
}, {
  name: "B",
  salary: 5
}, {
  name: "C",
  salary: 12
}]

const {
  persons: persons_,
  salarySum
} = persons.reduce((result, person) =>
  result.persons.push({
    ...person,
    salarySum: (result.salarySum += person.salary)
  }) && result, {
    salarySum: 0,
    persons: []
  })

console.log(persons_)
console.log(salarySum)
```